# Cant use page routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

So I'm working an a project where the user should click the link and than should go on the login or create account page. I'm using `routing` for that but as soon as I put Routes to use route and add the navigation link there my webpage turns **blank**:[image]
That was the code and this is the page at the moment:[image]
No error shown no nothing! help pls!

First I used `Switch` than the webpage didn't allow me to use it, so I changed to **Routes**

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Where do you use your `sign` component? Or better, can you provide [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: What react-router version are you using? Goto package.json file in the root directory of your project and check for `react-router-dom` in the dependencies section.

Comment: This is the version of react-router-dom: ^6.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="login" exact>
    <Login />
  </Route>
  <Route path="create" exact>
    <Signup />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

It should be like

```
<Routes>
    <Route exact path="login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/create" element={<Signup />} />
</Routes>
```

Here is a link to [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-pond-34p9of?file=/src/App.js)

Here is how to [render pages without navbar](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-snowflake-5ocvqn)

Comment: Okk thanks now the link works but it doesn't open a new page, it opens it in the same page that I'm in!

Comment: It seems like you are new to react. So, let's break it down. Everything you write outside of Routes will be rendered on each page.  Its because you want these links probably as navbar. So showing navbar only on one page would be a bad design. You can tell the page is changing by looking at the addressbar of your browser.

Comment: You said that everything I write outside the Routes will be rendered on each page, ok this is good for navbar, but what if I want to only render the page in link and not other elements(pages). Would I have to put everything in Routes so they wont render?, because this doesn't work.

Comment: I have just updated the answer. Kindly have a look at second codesandbox link and let me know if there is any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

So i wrote it wrong instead it should be written like this:

```
<Routes>
    <Route exact path="login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/create" element={<Signup />} />
</Routes>
```

But everything else that is outside the Routes will be render in the other page too, this is very useful for navbar!